# update_attributes NoMethodError when form value contains question mark in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, update-attributes

When I try and update a field with a value containing a '?', update_attributes returns:

```
**NoMethodError**
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.reverse
```

My controller is able to:

- Create a record with '?' as a field name.
- Edit/Save a record if a field containing '?' is left unchanged
- Edit/Save a record if a field containing '?' is changed to 'test'

Not able to:

- Edit/Save a record if a field containing '?' is changed to '?test' or 'test?'
- Edit/Save a record if a field containing 'test' is changed to '?'

I imagine active_record ignores unchanged fields, which is why the code works in this case.

I also see BEGIN and ROLLBACK in the log, so I assume the the error is caused by update_record failing to quote the string before passing it to the database. Is this a bug or am I supposed to quote form input explicitly?

My update method:

```
def update
  @interface = Interface.find(params[:id])
  if @interface.update_attributes(params[:interface])
     redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @interface.id
  else
     redirect_to :action => 'edit' 
  end
end
```

The model is blank.

Using update_attributes!, the message is (edit, still):

```
NoMethodError in Admin::InterfacesController#update
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.reverse
```

Sorry, the ArgumentError I mentioned was irrelevant.

Original stack trace: http://pastebin.com/JQ3Cmrba

---

FIXED by reverting to rails 3.0.7 and mysql 0.2.7.

Possible cause:

'username' and 'password' are fields within the interface table. The interface_controller inherits from a base_controller:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'
  before_filter :authenticate

  def index
  end
  protected

  def authenticate
     authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        if username == 'test' and password == 'pass'
           true
        else
           false
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: some code related to the error/stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: Try running it with `update_attributes!`. This will raise an exception (if raised) and possibly provide more useful info.

Comment: Can you try this in the latest patch set of Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: I can if I have to. Are 3.1 gems incompatible with ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: @Zameer. Using 1.9.2 didn't immediately fix the error. For the moment I've got around it by downgrading rails to 3.0.7 and mysql2 to 0.2.7.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error. for me, it was the gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', which i fixed by using the git version:

> -gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
>   +gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :git => 'https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git'

seems like this was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/commit/837cd489591afbb24f6ba4d36a15a6c4da82b063

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is in some ActiveRecord callback. Try looking it in some after_save, or other callback. Somewhere you are using the reverse function on a nil object. It maybe that you are getting nil as a result of processing when the value contains ?. We could help better if you post the callback code.

Comment: I think this probably is not the cause, but I'll update my post with the contents of the base_controller. As I said to Zameer before I noticed your reply, I fixed the error by reverting to rails 3.0.7 and mysql2 0.2.7.